# Scribe-java 1.3.3 How to remember a user?

Tags: android, authentication, oauth-2.0, scribe

I am using scribe 1.3.3 for OAuth2 in my android application.

I have gotten the full flow to work correctly with google, I can request user information and everything works fine.

I'm curious as to how to keep the user logged in if they close the app. Currently every time I start up the app I prompt the user to allow access.

How do I make it so that they only have to allow access once and from then on I just remember the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to remember the user. All you have to do is to remember the access token you got the first time. You can store it in shared preferences and use it to sign new requests.

So, the first time your activity starts you have to check whether the token is stored or not. You ask for credential only if the token is empty. Also note that your token may expire and if you get a 401 error you'll have to re authenticate the user.

PS: I wrapped scribe in an android library to make it easier to use with android: https://github.com/fedepaol/PostmanLib--Rings-Twice--Android

Comment: Ok, two question I have for that:

How can I store the access token in shared prefs. (Considering it's not a string, int, or anything like that)?

If I get a 401 error will I the user have to allow access again?

Comment: I've figured out a solution to my first question. My solution was to serialize it into a json string and then store it.

Comment: The access token is made of three strings:   public Token(String token, String secret, String rawResponse). You can store them separately in a sharedpreference or serialize them as you did. If you get a 401 error it might be the case that the token has expired. In that case you should reauthenticate the user and get a new token (the same way you are doing now).

Comment: I store accessToken info (token, secret, rawResponse) into DB, and using this info check in second login, it work OK. But when I logout gmail from browser, the accessToken still live, not expire!! Can you write more suggest??